# How to get div by class in HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I'm [following this tutorial](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples), but I have a problem, I don't know how to get `htmlNode` by class name .

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(e.Result);
HtmlNode divContainer = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("directoryItems");//My problem here,I want to get by class name html
if (divContainer != null)
{
     HtmlNodeCollection nodes = divContainer.SelectNodes("//table/tr");
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
HtmlNodeCollection divContainer = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='myClass']");
```

this will return a collection of div nodes with **class="myClass"**

Comment: but it get error "HtmlNodeCollection.HtmlAgilityPack does not contain a defintion for SelectNodes....." in HtmlNodeCollection nodes = divContainer.SelectNodes("//table/tr");

Comment: SelectNodes returns an collection of HtmlNodes, not just a single node, since the Class is not guaranteed to be unique. You could do `.First` if you're only interested in the first occurance.

Comment: @user2782709 see the comment above, it explains clearly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to select a `<div>` element having class attribute value equals "directoryItems", and you know there will be only one element meets the criteria (or you want to simply select the first occurrence if there are more then one), you can use `.SelectSingleNode()` method with following XPath query :

```
HtmlNode divContainer = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                               .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='directoryItems']");
```